# ListHeaderComponent Not Rendering

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I have a `ListHeaderComponent` with a horizontal `FlatList` inside it that is not being rendered properly. (It will only render when I hot reload).

Here is my code

### DATA FETCHING

```
const getData = async () => {
  Promise.all([getVenues(), getCategories()])
    .then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

### RENDERING

```
const listHeaderComponent = useCallback(() => {
  return <HomeListHeader language={language} categories={categories} />;
}, [language]);

return (
    <>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          header: () => <HomeHeader headerPress={handleHeaderPress} />,
        }}
      />
      {loading ? (
        <View />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={venues}
          ListHeaderComponent={listHeaderComponent}
          renderItem={(item) => {
            return renderItem(item);
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
```

### LIST HEADER COMPONENT

```
export default function HomeListHeader({ language, categories }) {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const backgroundColor = Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].background;
  const lightGray = Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].lightGray;
  const tintColor = Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].tint;
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleCategoryPress = (item) => {
    router.push({
      pathname: "home/category",
      params: {
        categoryName: item[language].name,
      },
    });
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => handleCategoryPress(item)}
        style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: lightGray }]}>
        <Text style={[styles.itemName, { color: tintColor }]}>
          {item[language].name}
        </Text>
      </Pressable>
    );
  });

  const itemSeparatorComponent = () => {
    return <View style={{ width: 10 }} />;
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={categories}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparatorComponent}
      horizontal
      contentInset={{ right: 40 }}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}
    />
  );
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Reading into [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402343/flatlist-props-listheadercomponent-and-dynamic-flatlist-data](https://here)

I added categories to my dependency for the ListHeaderComponent which has solved the issue

```
  const listHeaderComponent = useCallback(() => {
    return <HomeListHeader language={language} categories={categories} />;
  }, [language, categories]);
```